# Is it possible to make a Toffoli gate using only CNOTS and ancillas?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

I have tried to make a Toffoli gate using only CNOTs and some ancilla qubits but I do not get the unitary. It seems it is not possible without additional gates? What could I do to prove it?

I have tried something like `CNOT(c0,a0)`,`CNOT(c1,a0)`,`X(a0)`,`CNOT(a0,t)` (and then reversing the whole operation for the ancilla) , where `c` are the control qubits, `a` are the ancilla qubits and `t` is the target. This method does not work because when `c0` and `c1` are both 0 then it also changes the target qubit.

I know that you can generalize Toffoli to $n$ qubits using normal Toffolis and ancillas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not possible. One argument is the following:

Toffoli + Hadamard are universal for quantum computation, so if you can make Toffoli from controlled-not then controlled-not + Hadamard would be universal.

However, we know (Gottesman-Knill theorem) that the effects of controlled-not + Hadamard can be classically simulated, and so if we believe that there are algorithms that have a (more than polynomial) quantum speedup, it must be that controlled-not + Hadamard is not universal.

---

Update: I like Markus Heinrich's comment because it does simplify this specific argument. It helps us to focus more on the key properties of my original statement. We know that Hadamard+Toffoli is universal for quantum computation. That means, at least within some big subspace, and, specifically, starting from the all-0 state, any unitary can be created. On the other hand, the Gottesman-Knill theorem tells us that the Clifford gates (including c-NOT and Hadamard) form a finite group when acting on the input of all-0s. As such, they cannot recreate the action of Toffoli.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Do you know if I could I reduce the number of cnots to make a Toffoli using ancillas and single qubit gates? (probably I should open another question for that)

Comment: I believe you don't get any improvement over the standard construction. There are papers such as this: https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2316 which claim to prove that 6 cNOTs is the minimum. I assume that applies to the case with ancillas as well, but have not checked.

Comment: Oh that make sense. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems that you argument uses heavy machinery and unproven complexity-theoretic assumptions:) There should be a way to settle the problem in simple terms, should not it?

Comment: I like @Weather_Report’s question. The OP’s problem is a question about a purely classical synthesis. Maybe you could show it by trying to prove that it could be possible, failing, adding another ancilla, failing, and then recursing.

Comment: @WeatherReport I agree that complexity-theoretic machinery should be unnecessary, but it is a relatively simple argument to make. You might rather rely on proofs such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.4134 which explicitly calculate the minimum number of T gates when using clifford + T in order to create Toffoli (the point being it's non-zero)

Comment: @MarkS I also agree that it's a purely classical question as posed. Presumably my argument could be reduced to a classical one - Toffoli is universal for reversible classical computation. I presume (although I wouldn't know off the top of my head how to prove it) that controlled-not is not universal for reversible classical computation.

Comment: That said (re complexity theoretic treatment), that paper explicitly excludes ancillas.

Comment: The original answer to my question above is simple enough. for my second question see corollary 34: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2316.pdf

Comment: @DaftWullie no complexity-theoretic assumption needed. The group generated by CNOT and Hadamard is simply finite.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the discussion in @DaftWullie's answer above, note that we can construct a lattice/Hasse diagram of all classes of Boolean functions realizable/synthesizable with various gate sets.  Such a lattice will indicate whether a given gate set is universal for the given class.

For classical (not necessarily reversible) computation, Emil Post [did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice) this in the 40's.  Thus we have, for example, the well-known results that the [0, 1, ∧, ∨] are only able to synthesize "monotone" functions.

Apparently the same question went mostly unasked throughout most of the history of reversible computation; nonetheless, not too long ago [Aaronson, Grier, and Schaeffer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05155) were able to build such a lattice.  Their full classification allows for ancillas, and clocks in at 68 pages, but their Theorem 3 separates the class of functions realizable with CNOTs from those realizable with Toffoli gates.

Briefly and from a quick perusal of the above paper, CNOT gates (even with extra ancillas) are affine over $\mathbb{F}_2$, while CCNOT gates (Toffoli gates) are not.  Thus CNOT gates alone cannot synthesize non-affine functions, while Toffoli gates can.

Being affine means that, for a circuit $G$ (including ancillas initialized arbitrarily to $0$ or $1$ if necessary), then there exists an invertible matrix $A\in\mathbb{F}_2^{k\times k}$ and a vector $b$ such that $G(x)=Ax\otimes b$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If your inputs are bits $b_1, ..., b_n$ and you can only use NOT gates and CNOT gates, then your outputs are always parities. Your outputs are always of the form $c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n c_k b_k$ where $c_k \in \{0, 1\}$ are bits you can pick and also all arithmetic is modulo 2. For example, you can output $\lnot b_1$ and you can output $b_1 + b_3$ but you can't output $b_1 \cdot b_3$ or $b_1 \cdot b_3 + b_2$.

With a Toffoli gate, you can easily output a bit equal to $b_1 \cdot b_3 + b_2$. Just perform a Toffoli controlled by bits 1 and 3 targeting bit 2. Since the Toffoli gate enables you to do something you can't do with NOTs and CNOTs, you can't build a Toffoli out of NOTs and CNOTs.